# Http POST request and 400 Bad Request error

Tags: post, request, fiddler

We have an enterprise account for Stream Hub product of LiveFyre. Based on the documentation given below:

https://github.com/Livefyre/livefyre-docs/wiki/StreamHub-API-Reference#wiki-create-a-collection

I am trying to send a request to 'Create Collection' service both using Fiddler and problematically. I constantly get 400 Bad Request error when I send the request. Even the sample given in the documentation fails with 400 Bad Request error.

My request is:

- URL: `http://quill.sbs-int-0.fyre.co/api/v3.0/site/303821/collection/create/`
- Body: `{"articleId": "942619", "collectionMeta": "AAA"}`
- Host: `quill.sbs-int-0.fyre.co`
- Content-type: `application/json`
- Method: `POST`

Is there anything wrong with the request that I'm trying to send? Any way I can investigate the issue?

Comment: Did you really set the body to "AAA" as shown in the above, or did you create a body that follows the actual specification?

Comment: I created the body following the actual specification. I changed it to AAA for safety reasons.  Do you think it makes a difference? Bad Request means that HTTP Request is malformed or the service endpoint has a different parameter list etc. If the collectionMeta parameter has an invalid value, the service must receive the request and then throw an error saying that parameter's value is not valid. But what happens now is that the web server rejects the request. Am I right?

Comment: I have found something very strange. The service call works on a Linux box (when called by curl). It is also OK when I make the service call using RESTClient Firefox add-on ! It fails only when I make the call either with .NET code, Curl for Windows and Fiddler. What can be the issue?!!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out something was wrong with Fiddler! I used PostMan and FireFox's restful client and they worked fine. I uninstalled Fiddler and re-installed it and then 400 error went away!